# define and call a method inside CreateElement

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to reactjs and still learning, I need to define a method and call that method inside the CreateElement in Reactjs. Not sure if that is possible or i might be doing something in wrong way.

I am trying to test a method that has a if-else condition in it based on that a text should be dispayed thought react.

```
render: function render() {
    test_method:  function test_method(){  // <= if this should be placed here or 
    // outside render, Tried placing it outside render with this.
    // but not reading the value of a
    if (this.a == true){
        return a;
    } else {
        return b; 
    },

    React.createElement(
        'li',
        null,
        this.test_method
    );
};
```

Comment: Are you using es6 / es2015?

Comment: You want to pass this method as children of 'li'? You doing something wrong.

Comment: He wants to call the method and have it return the children of his li

Comment: I am using es2015

Comment: Place all the code and we can say why `this.a` is not being accessible with outside method.

Comment: I am getting this error : `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'a' of null` if i try using the  same method outside the render.

Answer (score 1):

First, as a parameter to `createElement`, when you pass `this.test_method`, you should instead use `this.test_method()`. The first, `this.test_method` will pass in the function itself. The second, with `()` added, will call the function and pass in what that function returns - ie, your child element.

As for your `test_method`, there's a few ways you can do it:

1) Define your test_method as a variable inside your render function

```
render: function render() {
    const test_method = () => { 
        if (this.a == true){
            return a;
        } else {
            return b; 
        }
    }

    return React.createElement(
        'li',
        null,
        test_method()
    );
};
```

2) Pull it outside your render, but bind the value of this to your function in your class' constructor. Something like:

```
constructor: function(props) {
    super(props)
    this.test_method = this.test_method.bind(this)
}

test_method: function() { 
    if (this.a == true){
        return a;
    } else {
        return b; 
    }
}

render: function render() {
    return React.createElement(
        'li',
        null,
        this.test_method()
    );
};
```

Comment: thanks. You've got a better eye for untested code than I do!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
export default class My_Class extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.a = "MY_VALUE";
        this.b = "My other value";
    }

    test_method = () => { 
        if (this.a == true){
            return this.a;
        } else {
            return this.b; 
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <li>this.test_method()</li>
        );
    }
}
```

Right now I can not prove it but it must go there. In any case the following may be simpler:

```
export default class My_Class extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    test_method(MY_A_VALUE) { 
        if (MY_A_VALUE == true){
            return MY_A_VALUE;
        } else {
            return "MY_B_VALUE"; 
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <li>this.test_method(MY_A_VALUE)</li>
        );
    }
}
```